# Sequelize one-to-many query (with include) produces Y is not associated to X

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, one-to-many

so i'm having problems with sequelize's one to many relationship, my associations are defined like this:

```
X.hasMany(Y, { as: 'Ys' });
Y.belongsTo(X, { as: 'X' });
```

and my findAll is here:

```
return X.findAll(
        {
            where: {
                something: something,
            },
            include: [{ model: db.Y, as: 'Ys' }]
        }
    );
```

and this is producing the error:

> "error": "Y (Ys) is not associated to X!"

Not quite sure what i'm doing wrong here :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some confusion on your associations

logically 'X' has many 'Ys', association should be `X.hasMany(Y, {as: 'Ys'});`

'Y' belongs to 'X' should be `Y.hasMany(X, {as: 'X'});`

Comment: it actually resolved my issue, thanks for this i will mark this as the correct answer.